# How can I host a large list in my 8G DDR3 RAM?

Tags: python, python-3.x, memory

I am new to python and just wondering how memory allocation works there. 
It turns out that one way to measure the size of a variable stored is to use `sys.getsizeof(x)` and it will return the number of bytes that are occupied by `x` in the memory, right? The following is an example code:

```
import struct
import sys

x = struct.pack('<L', 0xffffffff)
print(len(x))
print(sys.getsizeof(x))
```

which gives:

```
4
37
```

The variable `x` that I have just created is a 4-byte string and the first question rises here. Why is the memory allocated to a 4-byte string is `37` bytes? Is not that too much extra space?

The story gets more complicated when I start to create a list of 2 * 4-byte strings.
Bellow you will find another few lines:

```
import struct
import sys

k   = 2
rng = range(0, k)

x = [b''] * k

for i in rng:
    x[i] = struct.pack('<L', 0xffffffff)

print(len(x))
print(len(x[0]))
print(sys.getsizeof(x))
print(sys.getsizeof(x[0]))
```

from which I get:

```
2
4
80
37
```

Another question is that why when I store two 4-byte strings in a list the total sum of the memory allocated to them is not equal to the sum of their solo sizes?! That is `37 + 37 != 80`. What are those extra 6 bytes for?

Lets enlarge `k` to `10000`, the previous code gives:

```
10000
4
80064
37
```

Here the difference rises dramatically when comparing the solo size to the whole: `37 * 10000 = 370000 != 80064`. It looks like that each item in the list is now occupying `80064/10000 = 8.0064` bytes. Sounds feasible but I still cannot address previously shown conflicts.

After all, the main question of mine is that when I rise `k` to `0xffffffff` and expect to get a list of size `~ 8 * 0xffffffff = 34359738360` I actually encounter an exception of MemoryError. Is there any way to eliminate non-critical memory spaces so that my 8G DDR3 RAM can host this variable `x`?

Comment: Just because you have 8 GB installed, doesn't mean Python has access to all of it. E.g. Your OS and other processes need RAM as well

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Why is the memory allocated to a 4-byte string is 37 bytes? Is not that too much extra space?

*All* objects in Python have some amount of "slop" on a per-object basis.  Note that in the case of `bytes` and probably all immutable stdlib types, this padding (here 33 bytes) is *independent* of the length of the object:

```
from sys import getsizeof as gso
print(gso(b'x'*1000) - gso(b''))
# 1000
```

Note, this ***is not*** the same as:

```
print(gso([b'x']*1000) - gso(b''))
# 8031
```

In the former, you're making a `bytes` object of 1000 x's.

In the latter, you're making a list of 1000 bytes objects.  The important distinction is that in the latter, you're (a) replicating the bytes object 1000 times, *and* incorporating the size of the list container.  (The reason for the difference being only ~8,000 and not ~34,000 (i.e. 8 bytes per element instead of 34 bytes per element (=`sizeof(b'x')`) comes next.)

Lets talk about containers:

```
print(gso([b'x'*100,]) - gso([]))
```

Here we print the difference between the `getsizeof` of a one element list (of a 100 byte long `byte` object) and an empty list.  We're effectively [taring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tare_weight) out the size of the container.

We might expect that this is equal to `getsizeof(b'x' * 100)`.

It is not.

The result of `print(gso([b'x'*100,]) - gso([]))` is 8 bytes (on my machine) and is because the list contains just references/pointers to underlying objects and those 8 bytes are just that -- the pointer to the single element of the list.

> That is 37 + 37 != 80. What are those extra 6 bytes for?

Lets do the same thing and look at the net size, by subtracting the size of the container:

```
x = [b'\xff\xff\xff\xff', b'\xff\xff\xff\xff']

print(gso(x[0]) - gso(b''))   # 4
print(gso(x)    - gso([]))    # 16
```

In the first, the 4 returned is just as the 1000 returned in the first example I provided, one per byte.  (`len(x[0])` is 4).

In the second, it's 8 bytes per reference-to-sublist.  It has nothing to do with the *contents* of those sublists:

```
N = 1000
x = [b'x']    * N
y = [b'xxxx'] * N
print(gso(x) == gso(y))
# True
```

But while mutable containers don't seem to have a fixed "slop":

```
lst = []
for _ in range(100):
    lst.append('-')
    x = list(lst)

    slop = gso(x) - (8 * len(x))
    print({"len": len(x), "slop": slop})
```

Output:

```
{'len': 1, 'slop': 88}
{'len': 2, 'slop': 88}
{'len': 3, 'slop': 88}
{'len': 4, 'slop': 88}
{'len': 5, 'slop': 88}
{'len': 6, 'slop': 88}
{'len': 7, 'slop': 88}
{'len': 8, 'slop': 96}
{'len': 9, 'slop': 120}
{'len': 10, 'slop': 120}
{'len': 11, 'slop': 120}
{'len': 12, 'slop': 120}
{'len': 13, 'slop': 120}
{'len': 14, 'slop': 120}
{'len': 15, 'slop': 120}
{'len': 16, 'slop': 128}
{'len': 17, 'slop': 128}
{'len': 18, 'slop': 128}
{'len': 19, 'slop': 128}
{'len': 20, 'slop': 128}
{'len': 21, 'slop': 128}
{'len': 22, 'slop': 128}
{'len': 23, 'slop': 128}
{'len': 24, 'slop': 136}
...
```

...*Immutable* containers do:

```
lst = []
for _ in range(100):
    lst.append('-')
    x = tuple(lst)

    slop = gso(x) - (8 * len(x))
    print({"len": len(x), "slop": slop})
```

```
{'len': 1, 'slop': 48}
{'len': 2, 'slop': 48}
{'len': 3, 'slop': 48}
{'len': 4, 'slop': 48}
{'len': 5, 'slop': 48}
{'len': 6, 'slop': 48}
{'len': 7, 'slop': 48}
{'len': 8, 'slop': 48}
{'len': 9, 'slop': 48}
{'len': 10, 'slop': 48}
{'len': 11, 'slop': 48}
{'len': 12, 'slop': 48}
{'len': 13, 'slop': 48}
{'len': 14, 'slop': 48}
...
```

> Is there any way to eliminate non-critical memory spaces so that my 8G DDR3 RAM can host this variable x?

First, recall that the sizeof a container will not reflect the entire amount of memory used by Python.  The ~8 bytes per element is *the size of the pointer*, each of those elements will consume an additional 37 (or whatever) bytes (sans interning or similar optimization).

But the good news is that it's unlikely you probably don't need the *entire* list at the same time.  If you're just building a list to iterate over, then generate it one element at a time, with a for loop or generator function.

Or generate it a chunk at a time, process it, and then continue, letting the garbage collector clean up the no-longer-used memory.

---

One other interesting thing to point out

```
N = 1000
x = [b'x' for _ in range(N)]
y = [b'x'] * N
print(x == y)              # True
print(gso(x) == gso(y))    # False
```

(This is likely due to the size of `y` being known *a priori*, while the size of `x` is not and has been resized as it grew).